# Columns & diagonalizability of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

I want to solve this question:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix over a field $k,$ all of whose columns are the same. Describe the conditions under which $A$ is diagonalizable. Justify your answer.

I saw this question [Diagonalizability and linear independence of columns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2529963/diagonalizability-and-linear-independence-of-columns) here, but I do not know what is the relation between minimal polynomials and diagonalizability and columns, could someone explain this to me please?

Does linear independence of columns imply diagonal matrix but the reverse is not true? how this help me in answering my question above?

Comment: You can think about diagonalizability and the minimal polynomial in terms of eigenvectors: $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ is diagonalizable iff there is a basis for $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$ iff the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces is $n$ iff the minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors over $\mathbb{C}$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix).

Comment: And how is this related to columns @JWP_HTX?

Comment: Can you take a matrix with same columns and compute the minimal polynomial? Then just look at linear factors

Comment: I think I can do so yes.@JWP_HTX

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that the rank of such a matrix is either $0$ or $1$. What does that tell you about the eigenvectors of this matrix? From there, consider the trace of the matrix and what this trace tells you about the matrix's eigenvalues.